# Hide rows in listview only for particular listitems in xamarin

Tags: listview, xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms

I have a grouped listView in my xaml.

Here is the listView object:

Attachment:

```
public string TCPNumber { get; set; }
public string AttachmentName { get; set; }
public int FileType { get; set; }
```

These groups are names as X and Y based on FileType value.
Each list item shows values for the above 3 items.
I want to hide TCPNumber item in group Y list items where filetype value is 2.

Below is my xaml:

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <converter:TCPGridVisibleConverter x:Key="TCPGridVisible" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
<ContentPage.Resources>

<ListView x:Name="lvTCPs" HasUnevenRows="True"
<ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout>
                            <Label Text="{Binding Key}"/>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
<RowDefinition Height="{Binding Path=FileType, Source={x:Reference 
Name=AttachmentsTabPage}, Converter={StaticResource TCPGridVisible}}"> 
</RowDefinition>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"></ColumnDefinition>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
</ListView>
```

This is the way I'm trying to hide 1st row of the ViewCell, but no success.
Any help?

Comment: if you want to hide an entire row I think it would be easier to just not include it in the ItemsSource in the first place

Comment: I want to hide the row only if the FileType value of listitem is 2 or else I need to populate that row

Comment: then why don't you filter out FileType=2 when building your ItemsSource?

Comment: actually my requirement is not removing list items. I want to remove/hide 1st row of each list item whose fileType value is 2. How is it possible to filter out with itemsource

Comment: you really need to edit your question to clarify that you mean **row of the ViewCell Grid**, not **row of ListView**

Comment: yes sorry for confusion. So any suggestion to achieve this?

Comment: Did you try by adding an `IsVisible` property and bind it to some property on your viewmodel ?

Comment: I'm setting row height value to 0 but its not working. I don't think Rowdefinition has IsVisible proprty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote a demo about hide TCPNumber item in group Y list items where filetype value is 2.

First of all, i set `TCPNumber`,`AttachmentName`,`FileType` in defferent row of listview item. when filetype value is 2, the `TCPNumber` of first row will be hide like following screenshot.[image]

There is my xaml.

```
   <StackLayout>
    <ListView x:Name="lvTCPs" HasUnevenRows="True" >
                <ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <StackLayout>
                                <Label Text="KEY"/>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>

                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                <RowDefinition Height="{Binding FileType, Converter={local:TCPGridVisibleConverter} }"></RowDefinition>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


                        <Label Text="{Binding TCPNumber}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" />
                        <Label Text="{Binding AttachmentName}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" />
                        <Label Text="{Binding FileType}" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" />

                    </Grid>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>


</StackLayout>
```

There is my `TCPGridVisibleConverter`.

```
    public class TCPGridVisibleConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (Equals(value, null))
            return new GridLength(0);

        var status = value.ToString();

        switch (status)
        {
            case ("2"):
                {
                    return new GridLength(0);
                }
            default:
                {

                    return new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Auto);
                }
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value;
    }
}
```

There is my data.

```
        List<TCP> list = new List<TCP>();
        list.Add(new TCP("1001","abc",2));
        list.Add(new TCP("1002", "bca", 1));
        list.Add(new TCP("1003", "bca", 2));
        list.Add(new TCP("1004", "abc", 1));
        list.Add(new TCP("1005", "abc", 1));
        lvTCPs.ItemsSource = list;
```

There is your model.

```
    public class TCP
{
    public TCP(string TCPNumber, string AttachmentName, int FileType)
    {
        this.TCPNumber = TCPNumber;
        this.AttachmentName = AttachmentName;
        this.FileType = FileType;

    }
    public string TCPNumber { get; set; }
    public string AttachmentName { get; set; }
    public int FileType { get; set; }
}
```

Hope it can help you.

Comment: Yes, it helped. Thank you.